# TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, npm

I try to install node.js modules using:

```
npm install express
```

but I get this error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
npm ERR!     at Agent.request (_http_agent.js:264:11)
npm ERR!     at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:52:22)
npm ERR!     at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:117:25)
npm ERR!     at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:184:41)
npm ERR!     at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:80:8)
npm ERR!     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:112:16)
npm ERR!     at Agent.request (_http_agent.js:279:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.exports.request (https.js:130:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:594:30)
npm ERR!     at Request.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:1186:28)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11-7.fc16.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/src/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.5-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/src/node/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

May be happening I use a proxy I set it up this way to allow downloads from ips outside my network

```
export https_proxy='http://172.21.0.12:3128'
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Set proxy from commandline.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxydomain:port/
```

If error occur yet, additional try next.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

These work for me.
(ref http://sushichop.blogspot.jp/2013/01/npm-install.html)

Comment: It took both lines to work for me. Thanks! Any idea why my machine wide Ubuntu proxy setting isn't working for this?

Comment: sometimes the connection does not allow the proxy to connect to remote resources npm installer

Answer (score 2):

Though late enough, I've bumped into this too after updating nodejs (to 4.1.1) and npm (to something like 1.4.x) on Linux.

I've tried the suggested solution, but changing the registry entry did not help in all cases.
Lastly, having decided to reinstall npm, I found this update source [on npm github][1]

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

which updated my npm to 3.3.8 and all related package installation troubles have been blown away.