# Nodejs module install error : Request path contains unescaped characters

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I'm new to nodejs, npm and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Any guesses ? [I've tried this, but it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006179/typeerror-request-path-contains-unescaped-characters)

```
npm install -g mongoose
```

---

```
1220 http GET https://github.com/mongodb-js/node-pre-gyp/archive/v0.6.5-appveyor.tar.gz
1221 error TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
1221 error     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)
1221 error     at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
1221 error     at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
1221 error     at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25)
1221 error     at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)
1221 error     at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8)
1221 error     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
1221 error     at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
1221 error     at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
1221 error     at Request.start (C:\software\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:583:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` trying to use `https` to get the tar because of ambiguous configuration in '.npmrc' file. Here's the old config:

```
prefix = C:\software\nodejs
strict-ssl = false
http-proxy = http://[username]:[password]@[domain]:8080/
https-proxy = https://[username]:[password]@[domain]:8080/
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

---

Changing it to this resolve the issue:

```
prefix = C:\software\nodejs
http-proxy = http://[username]:[password]@[domain]:8080/

#angularjs2 require proxy as key, http-proxy gave the above error
proxy = http://[username]:[password]@[domain]:8080/

registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```